# Replication from a secondary in a high availability group

Tags: sql-server, replication, high-availability

We have a couple of servers in a SQL Server HA group, one acting as primary and the other as secondary. This system is working fine and fails over as expected (though this is very rare).  However we also want to set up transactional replication for another purpose, to enable some integration with data pushed by one of the DBs in the HA group.  The integration would like the data be as real time as possible (hence transactional, some latency is fine) and a one way Push from one of the servers in the HA group.

I am thinking to use the Secondary only for the transactional replication and not make any changes to the Primary. The Secondary doesn't get much use and when it does fail over, we quickly fix the issue on the Primary and fail back manually to the Primary. The Primary is under reasonably heavy usage and is a little fragile, while the Secondary has much less usage, so using the Secondary as the Publisher seems like a smart solution.

1. Is this possible to use the Secondary only as the Publisher, with no changes on the Primary?
2. Assuming this is possible, anything to watch out for using this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is this possible to use the Secondary only as the Publisher, with no changes on the Primary?

No, in fact you can't use the Secondary as a Replication Publisher at all, even if you setup the Primary to be a Publisher as well. Only Primary replicas can be Publishers. Secondary replicas must be enabled for Replication so they are ready to take over as a Publisher when they become the new Primary, during a failover.

You can find the answer to this and more information in Microsoft's Books Online on [**Configure replication with Always On availability groups** - Configure the Secondary Replica Hosts as Replication Publishers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#step4):

> A secondary replica cannot act as a replication publisher or republisher but replication must be configured so that the secondary can take over after a failover.

Comment: Great, thanks JD, I had a suspicion this was the case but hadn't yet landed on that Microsoft page when searching. Thanks!

Comment: @blobbles Np, sorry it probably wasn't the answer you were hoping for. Replication, like any other technology adds overhead, but unless you're replicating a Table that's being constantly written to (e.g. 1,000s of rows per second) you likely won't find it to be too bothersome to your Primary. Best of luck!

Comment: Great, thanks J.D, also for your extra comment, because that was my next concern :-)